# Increase UITextField height while using Autolayout

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, autolayout

I have created a `UITextField` subclass and set its frame for custom height.

```
CGRect frame = self.frame;
frame.size.height = 40;
self.frame = frame;
```

Now in my `UIViewController` nib file, i just drag a `UITextField` object and set its custom class using Identity inspector. It is working fine. The of textfield's height is now 40.

The problem is when I enable Autolayout for this nib file, the textfield no more retain new height. Height goes back to default 30 again.

I think this is because in nib file, height is still 30, and Autolayout pin it to 30.

Any solution to set textfield height to 40 while using Autolayout?

**Edit:**

If i add 40px height constraint, i have to do this for all nibs in my project. Any solution to do this once? May be in custom `UITextField` class programatically?

Comment: add height constraint in xib file which equals 40

Comment: @Neil, Thanks for comment. I had already done this. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the way. I was stupid that didn't try earlier. In my `UITextField` custom class, i just replaced, following

```
CGRect frame = self.frame;
frame.size.height = 40;
self.frame = frame;
```

with

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                multiplier:0.0f
                                                  constant:40]];
```

It is working perfect now, without adding any code in  my `UIViewController` classes.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change it in code, make an outlet to it and change its constant value to 40. So, if your IBOutlet was called heightCon, do this:

```
self.heightCon.constant = 40;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How can i add this constraint in my UITextField subclass only once? So that i don't have to add it in all classes in my project.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *verticalConstraints = 
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(50)-[view(40)]" 
    options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsDictionary];
```

Now the view will be 50 pixels from the top of its superview, and 40 pixels tall.

Then in `-(void)awakeFromNib` method in your custom view class add line `[self addConstraints:verticalConstraints];`

The language used for the visual format string is described in ["Visual Format Language"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am still looking for more simpler way of adding a fixed 40px height to my textfields. With fewer line of codes and without handling any other method like "awakFromNib".

Comment: If you have IBOutlet to your custom class, then this method used to initialize state information after objects have been loaded from an Interface Builder archive (nib file).